# How to add correct mime type in html using spring?

Tags: java, html, spring

I am working on a Spring v-2.7.4 application in which I use SecurityFilterChain interface from spring framework security to add some roles to my web server. By default when implementing SecuirityFilterChain it also enables X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, this seems to make the browser block my javascript and css files. I understand that it is a good practice to enable this setting, but I can't find the correct way so that my browser does not reject my css or js templates. I have already tried to add the corresponding mime format to the routes in the headers according to this documentation: [https ://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)

However, it still continues unchanged. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link  href="css/homeview.css" type="text/css">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

...

<script src="Javascript/main.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add some whitelist configuration like 
```web.antMatchers("/*.js","*.css").permitAll()
``` in some subclasses of ```WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter``` or something?